# proof by contradiction (clarification)

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $U = \{k\in \mathbb{Z} : x \le k\}$, so $\inf U \ge x$, where $x \in \mathbb{R} $. I want to show that $\inf U < x+1$.  Prove this by contradiction.

Suppose $\inf U \ge x+1$. Then, as $\inf U \ge x$, $\inf U \ge \inf U+1$, which is a contradiction.

I don't understand this part. How do we know $\inf U \ge \inf U+1$ from the fact that $\inf U \ge x$?

Thank you in advance.

Edit: I uploaded the image file to clarify question. [image]
[image]

Comment: Are the first two lines taken from a text or something? $2 \geq 0$ and $2 \geq 0+1=1$ do not imply that $2 \geq 2+1$! I'm guessing there's an inequality flipped or copied wrong somewhere?

Comment: I don't think I copied wrong, but I captured the note for clarification.

Comment: What's the name of the book?

Comment: it is not a textbook. It is a solution for assignment. It is not clear, right??

Answer (score 1):

I can't start from $\inf{U} \ge x$ and $\inf{U} \ge x+1$ to get the contradiction you've given. But it seems like Gauss's notation works:

$$
\text{let }\lceil x\rceil = k' \\
$$
Since the infimum of $U$ should not greater than the least element in $U$,
$$
\inf{U} \le k' \\
$$
Now since you assumed $\lnot (\inf{U} < x+1),$
$$
x+1 \le \inf{U}\\
x \le \lceil x\rceil < x+1 \le \inf{U} \\
$$

So we have arrived a conclusion that $\inf{U} \le k' < \inf U$, which is a contradiction(You can't find an integer between ... an integer itself).